# How to get std::thread to do general construction of the arguments passed to its function?

Tags: c++, multithreading, templates, parameter-passing

`std::thread`'s constructor and similar interfaces such as `std::async` copy their parameters into thread-accessible storage as if by the function

```
template <class T>
typename decay<T>::type decay_copy(T&& v) {
    return std::forward<T>(v);
}
```

This function can handle move and copy constructors, but I wonder if it is possible to generalize the way these parameters are constructed similarly to how `.emplace()` generalizes `.insert()` in the standard container interfaces.

For example, I may have a movable type which is only constructible from an `int`:

```
struct foo
{
  foo(int arg){}
  foo(foo&& other){}

  foo() = delete;
  foo(const foo&) = delete;
};
```

Is it possible to create a `helper` for such types whose copy construction  via `decay_copy` would have the effect of constructing some other type?

I know how to create a solution which would copy `foo`'s parameters into the thread-accessible storage, but I want to avoid that (assume these parameters are enormous in general and thread-accessible storage is scarce).

Here is my initial attempt:

```
#include <thread>
#include <utility>

struct foo
{
  foo(int arg){}
  foo(foo&& other){}

  foo() = delete;
  foo(const foo&) = delete;
};


template<class T, class Arg>
struct helper
{
  operator T () const
  {
    return T{arg_};
  }

  Arg arg_;
};


template<class T, class Arg>
helper<T,Arg> help(Arg&& arg)
{
  return helper<T,Arg>{std::forward<Arg>(arg)};
}


int main()
{
  auto lambda = [](const foo& f){};

  std::thread t{lambda, help<foo>(13)};
  t.join();

  return 0;
}
```

The problem I have with this solution is that all of `foo`'s constructor parameters get copied into thread-accessible storage via the `helper` object. I only want to spend storage on the `foo` object.

Assuming I can't modify `lambda`, nor `std::thread`, is there some trick that will cause the `decay_copy` function to return a newly-constructed `foo` when given a `helper` as an argument?

Comment: Do you want to make `std::thread` create an object of type `foo` by the thread that called the constructor, but on the storage for the new thread?

Comment: @dyp: Yes, basically. Ideally the storage for the constructor parameters would only live in the parent thread's stack, and the storage for the `foo` object in the child thread's stack.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: Then, as I said in my answer, why not create `foo` in the parent and move it into the thread?

Comment: @rodrigo: Hard to explain. I don't have that option -- the constructor depends on the thread id executing it.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: Well then, why not to pass references to the arguments into your `helper` class, and build the `foo` in the `helper::operator T()`? A bit like my answer about `std::packaged_task`.

Comment: @rodrigo This can lead to lifetime issues.

Comment: @rodrigo: Because asynchrony. By the time `helper::operator T()` is called, those references may be invalid.

Comment: *"Hard to explain. I don't have that option -- the constructor depends on the thread id executing it."* At second glance, I don't quite get it yet. `foo` is move-constructible. Thread Alice calls the constructor of `std::thread` which creates thread Bob. Alice knows the `13` argument required to create a `foo`. Alice shall create a `foo` such that `Bob` can use it. No `int` shall be placed in `Bob`'s storage. Then, why not let `Alice` create a `foo` locally and move it into `Bob`'s storage?

Comment: @dyp: Thanks for considering the question. The full problem I'm trying to solve is beyond the scope of SO and the description in the question is just an approximation. The short answer is that in my application `Alice` just can't create a `foo` locally -- she can only give `Bob` the parameters to do so via the `std::thread` constructor.

Comment: Now I'm confused. If `Bob` shall create the `foo` himself, then `Alice` *has* to pass the construction arguments to `Bob` - either by value or by reference. (I thought `Alice` shall construct the `foo`, but in `Bob`'s storage)

Comment: @JaredHoberock: Now I think I got it. Please see my updated answer. It passes references to the arguments in the helper class and a `promise<void>` for synchronization. The trick is that the promise is fulfulled in the worker thread, just after `foo` is built.

Comment: @dyp: Sorry. By "locally" I simply meant the code which invokes `std::thread`'s constructor. The `Alice` thread constructs the `foo` object inside `std::thread`'s constructor.

Comment: I think this is not supported by `std::thread`'s interface. Internally, it needs to set up some storage for `Bob` and construct objects there such that `Bob` can access them in its main thread function. But it seems `std::thread` only supports copying or moving from one argument to one object on `Bob`'s storage of the same (decayed) type.

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what you mean with "thread-accesible storage" as all threads in a process usually share all their memory.

Maybe you refer to the stack, but then you just may pass the `foo` object fully constructed (in the main thread). The `foo` object will live in the thread stack:

```
foo f{13};
std::thread t{lambda, f};
```

A fancy option is to use `std::future`:

```
#include <future>
template<class T>
struct helper
{
  operator T ()
  {
    return future.get();
  }
  std::future<T> future;
};
template<class T>
helper<T> help(std::future<T> &&p)
{
  return helper<T>{std::forward<std::future<T>>(p)};
}
```

Then it can be used with a `std::promise`:

```
std::promise<foo> p;
//you can set the value before or after the thread
std::thread t{lambda, help(p.get_future())};
//either way, std::future::get() is a synchronization point
p.set_value(13);
t.join();
```

Or with a `std::packaged_task` and a labmda that creates the `foo`. But in this particular case, the lambda will be executed in the thread, so there would be no practical difference between that and your original code, I guess.

**UPDATE**: From your comments, I think that you can use your helper class with a simple `std::promise<void>` for syncrhonization:

```
template<class T>
struct helper
{
  operator T ()
  {
      foo f{x};
      promise.set_value(); // x is no longer needed
      return f;
  }

  std::promise<void> promise;
  int &x;
};


template<class T>
helper<T> help(std::promise<void> &&p, int &x)
{
  return helper<T>{std::forward<std::promise<void>>(p), x};
}

int main()
{
   auto lambda = [](const foo &&f){  };

   std::promise<void> prom_done;
   std::future<void> done = prom_done.get_future(); 

   int x = 42; 
   std::thread t{lambda, help<foo>(std::move(prom_done), x)}; 

   future.get(); //wait until the `foo` is fully created.

   t.join();
}
```

Comment: "thread-accessible storage" is the [language used in the documentation on cppreference.com](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread/thread). On my platform, threads do not share their memory.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: Ok, I've read it, but still do not get what it means, other than a vage feeling that it is a fancy way of saying nothing special.

Comment: @dyp: Thanks for taking the time to consider the question. Your answer won't solve my application unfortunately. In my application, I can't do any extra synchronization, dynamic allocation, or even modify the `main` function! :-) So it really all has to be localized to the `helper` template somehow. FWIW, I don't think there is a solution in c++14.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: You're welcome! So you want: 1) run the constructor in the worker thread; 2) not to copy or move the constructor arguments; 3) not to wait for the worker thread to finish running the constructor; 4) the constructor arguments will be destroyed immediately in the main thread. All these 4 together are impossible! Remove just one of these conditions and it will be easy.

Comment: Actually, the constructor needs to run in the parent thread. I want to avoid copying or moving the constructor arguments to the worker. In my solution, the constructor arguments get copied to the worker, and the worker invokes the constructor.

Comment: @JaredHoberock: But if the constructor is to be run in the parent thread, why don't you just do that and move the already created `foo` into the thread?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/69486/discussion-between-jared-hoberock-and-rodrigo).